# Comment System: JavaScript not 'returning' right comment_Id

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am building a basic commenting system for a website: Comments can be made and users can reply on every comment. I am using ajax for submitting and retrieving/displaying the comments and replies. I have successfully coded the comments part, but need assistance on the replies part.

Every comment stored in the database has a unique id (comment_id) associated with it. And I use that id to associate replies to each respective comment.

The form for the comments, which is in **index.php**:

```
<div id="showComments"></div> <!--div where comments are inserted by AJAX-->
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <form action="" method="post" id="commentForm">                             
        <textarea  name="comment" id="comment" rows="1"></textarea><BR>                                             
        <button type="submit" name="new_comment" onClick="submitComment()">Comment</button>                                                             
    </form>
    <div id="message"></div> <!--div where a status (comment submitted successfully or failed) is inserted by AJAX-->
</div>
```

The JavaScript for submitting the comment and displaying the comments, also in **index.php**.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    showComments();
});

function submitComment(){
var commentText =  document.getElementById('comment').value;
var commentString = 'comment=' + commentText;

event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
  url: "insert_com.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: commentString,
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(response) {
    if (!response.error) {
      $("#commentForm")[0].reset();   
      $("#message").html(response.message);
      showComments();
    } else if (response.error) {
      $("#message").html(response.message);
    }
  }
});
}

function showComments() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "get_com.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
      $("#showComments").html(response);
    }
  });
}

</script>
```

The file **insert_com.php**, which submits the comment to the database, to where AJAX posts in the `submitComment()` function:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST["comment"])){
    $new_com_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $insertComment = "INSERT INTO comments (text, date) VALUES ('".$_POST["comment"]."', '".$new_com_date."')";
    mysqli_query($connect, $insertComment) or die("database error: ". mysqli_error($connect));  
    $message = '<label>Comment posted Successfully.</label>';
    $status = array(
        'error'  => 0,
        'message' => $message
    );  
} else {
    $message = '<label>Error: Comment not posted.</label>';
    $status = array(
        'error'  => 1,
        'message' => $message
    );  
}
echo json_encode($status);
?>
```

And the file **get_com.php**, which retrieves and displays the comments ***but also retrieves the replies and contains the form for submitting the replies***

```
<?php 
    require 'php/connect.php';
    $comment =  mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY `date` DESC");
    $string ="";

    foreach($comment as $item) {
        $date = new dateTime($item['date']);
        $date = date_format($date, 'M j, Y | H:i:s');        
        $comment = $item['text'];
        $comment_id = $item['id'];       

        $string .= '<div style="text-align:center;">' 
                .'<div id="'.$comment_id.'" style="text-align:center;">'                        
                    .'<span><b>'.$comment.'</b></span>&nbsp'
                    .'<span><b>'.$date.'</b></span>&nbsp;'
                    .'<span><b>'.$comment_id.'</b></span>'
               .'</div>';

               $reply = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `replies` WHERE `comment_id`='$comment_id' ORDER BY `date` DESC");

                foreach($reply as $com) {
                    $reply_date = new dateTime($com['date']);
                    $reply_date = date_format($reply_date, 'M j, Y | H:i:s');                    
                    $reply_com = $com['text'];
                    $com_id = $com['comment_id'];                    

                    $string.= '<div>'                           
                                .'<span>'.$reply_com.'</span>&nbsp;'
                                .'<span class="time">'.$reply_date.'</span>&nbsp;'
                                .'<span><b>'.$com_id.'</b></span>' 
                            .'</div>';              
                }

                $string .= 

                '<div>'                   
                    .'<form action="" method="post" id="replyForm">'
                        .'<textarea name="new-reply" id="new-reply" rows="1"></textarea>'
                        .'<input type="hidden" id="com_id" name="com_id" value="'.$comment_id.'"/>'
                        .'<button type="submit" id="form-reply" name="new_reply" onClick="submitReply()">Reply</button>&nbsp;'
                        .'<span><b>'.$comment_id.'</b></span>'                      
                    .'</form>'
                    .'<span id="replymessage"></span>'
                .'</div>'

            .'</div>'
            .'<hr style="width:300px;">';


    }
    echo $string;
?>
```

Now, here is where the problem comes in. I want to use AJAX to submit a reply to a particular comment with an id `$comment_id`. I want to get this id from the hidden input contained in the reply form (The form with id `replyForm`.

I wrote the following JavaScript to retrieve the id belonging to a particular comment:

```
<script>
function submitReply(){

var replyText =  document.getElementById('new-reply').value; console.log(replyText);
var commId = document.getElementById('com_id').value; console.log(commId);

event.preventDefault();
...
</script>
```

As you can see, I log the form text (the reply) and the comment id to the console to see whether I am capturing the correct data, but it always returns the id of the last comment submitted. (i.e the reply form works for the last comment. The JavaScript logs the correct text and comment id for a reply on the last comment, but for all other replies it returns the text of the  reply on the last comment and the id of the last comment.

I know it's quite a lot of code, so if anyone more experience could assist me it would certainly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one element with `id="com_id"`. `id` should be unique. What you can do is when you are generating the DOM in `get_com.php`, instead of

```
'<input type="hidden" id="com_id" name="com_id" value="'.$comment_id.'"/>'
'<button type="submit" id="form-reply" name="new_reply" onClick="submitReply()">Reply</button>&nbsp;'
```

You can call `submitReply()` with the right ID, like so:

```
'<button type="submit" id="form-reply" name="new_reply" onClick="submitReply('.$comment_id.')">Reply</button>&nbsp;'
```

Then, the comment ID would be the argument of your `submitReply` method and you wouldn't need to read it from the input field.

```
<script>
  function submitReply(commId){

    var replyText =  document.getElementById('new-reply').value; 
    console.log(replyText);
    console.log(commId);

    event.preventDefault();
  ...
</script>
```

Your `<textarea>` has the same issue as well.
I suggest to assign a unique ID to your `<textarea>` as well, something like `"reply-'.$comment_id.'"`. Then, when `submitReply(comment_id)` gets called, you know which comment ID is the call for, so you can construct the unique ID for the exact same textarea, and get the value of the desired element.

```
<script>
  function submitReply(commId){

    var replyText =  document.getElementById('reply-' + commId).value; 
    console.log(replyText);
    console.log(commId);

    event.preventDefault();
  ...
</script>
```